# Finding the largest difference between two doubles in java without arrays

Tags: java

We're to find the difference between consecutive input values and return the largest change.
My main issue is finding the correct operator to use (I think). Also I wanted it to work with negative values..

```
if(count > 0){
      change = Math.abs(temp) - Math.abs(temp2);
      UI.println(change);
      if(Math.abs(change) > Math.abs(bigChange)){
           bigChange = Math.abs(change);
      }
}
```

Comment: you should use method Max instead of second If

Comment: There's no need to add "Solved" to the question or title, this is not a forum. The question is automatically marked as answered and specially marked when you accept an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of abs is incorrect. Consider the case where temp is -1 and temp2 is 1. The difference between these values is 2, but your routine will compute it as 0.

Try:

```
if(count > 0) {
  change = Math.abs(temp - temp2);
  UI.println(change);
  if( change > bigChange ) {
    bigChange = change;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much =) That did exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find the change between to numbers you should use

```
change = Math.abs(temp- temp2);
```

instead of

```
 change = Math.abs(temp) - Math.abs(temp2);
```

Also you should initialize the variable

```
bigChange=0
```

Furthermore, since variables change and bigChange are always greater than zero you can avoid calling again Math.abs method.

```
if(change > bigChange)
      {
          bigChange = change;
      }
```

is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple:

```
int diff = temp - temp2;
max = Math.max(maxDifference, Math.abs(diff));
println(max).
```

Do you have any other requirement?
Math.max and Math.min are quite optimized and are as fast as doing the comparison yourself. And it's a one-liner. See this answer as well for Math.max vs (a > b ? a : b)

[Is Math.max(a,b) or (a>b)?a:b faster in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103606/which-one-is-faster-in-java-1-math-maxa-b-2-abab)