# Java List looping based of available size

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I want to display only 12 sorted elements from `myList`. If the size is less than 12, say 5, or 3, or 1, still I need to loop and display only those available items.

Below is my code:

```
public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add("20150830");
        myList.add("20141201");
        myList.add("20150716");
        myList.add("20151131"); 
        myList.add("20141101");
        myList.add("20150620");
        myList.add("20150301");
        myList.add("20150702");
        myList.add("20150511");

        Collections.sort(myList,Collections.reverseOrder());

        for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(myList.get(i).toString());
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Try: `for(int i = 0; i < myList.size() && i < 12; i++){`

Comment: Alternatively `for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(myList.size(),12); i++){`

Comment: use list.sublist(from,to)

Comment: If there is more than 12 elements, should the first 12 still be printed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to iterate over a List in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Just add one more condition in your loop to restrict the loop for 12.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size() &&  i < 12 ; i++){
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use-case for streams.

```
myList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.<String>reverseOrder())
        .limit(12)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
int maxValuesToDisplay=12;
int maxToIterate=(myList.size()<maxValuesToDisplay) ? myList.size() : maxValuesToDisplay;

for(int i = 0; i < maxToIterate; i++){
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: Well, `Math.min` looks much better then this ternary operator :P.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);`

```
public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add("20150830");
        myList.add("20141201");
        myList.add("20150716");
        myList.add("20151131"); 
        myList.add("20141101");
        myList.add("20150620");
        myList.add("20150301");
        myList.add("20150702");
        myList.add("20150511");


        Collections.sort(myList,Collections.reverseOrder());
        int a = myList.size();
        List subList = null;
        if(a<12)
        subList = myList.subList(0,a);
        else subList = myList.subList(0,12);
       //Print sublist now 

 }     
    }
```

Comment: Combine this with Math.min() would be much cleaner: `List subList = myList.subList(0, Math.min(myList.size(), 12))`, all in 1 line, not 5

Comment: @MarkFisher True Mark :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Math.min()` function and iterate the minimum of `12` and the `list-size`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(myList.size(), 12); i++){
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).toString());
   }
```

Comment: This is not optimal as this compute the min on each loop.

Comment: list.size() is O(1) (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540511/time-complexity-for-java-arraylist) and Math.min(num, num) is hardly going to add any significant overhead.

Comment: Also Math.min() is same as the `<` operator, has no complexity. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103606/which-one-is-faster-in-java-1-math-maxa-b-2-abab). ThIs keeps the for statement clean.

Comment: Except this is an object oriented language and you don't know what is behind "size()". Anyway for optimization, always get out of the loops invariants you can compute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeSet :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> myList = new TreeSet<>();
    myList.add("20150830");
    myList.add("20141201");
    myList.add("20150716");
    myList.add("20151131");
    myList.add("20141101");
    myList.add("20150620");
    myList.add("20150301");
    myList.add("20150702");
    myList.add("20150511");

    int i = 0;
    for(String s : myList){
        System.out.println(s);
        i++;
        if(i >= 5) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And for reverse order :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> myList = new TreeSet<>();
        myList.add("20150830");
        myList.add("20141201");
        myList.add("20150716");
        myList.add("20151131");
        myList.add("20141101");
        myList.add("20150620");
        myList.add("20150301");
        myList.add("20150702");
        myList.add("20150511");

        Iterator<String> it = myList.descendingIterator();
        int i = 0;

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            String s = it.next();
            System.out.println(s);
            i++;
            if (i >= 5) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```