# java ternary operator can be replaced with Math.max call

Tags: java

I have the following code `delay = (delay>200) ? delay : 200;`
`Java` issues a warning message `Can be replaced with 'Math.max' call` for this.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103606/is-math-maxa-b-or-abab-faster-in-java) I see that `Math.max(a, b)` is actually the same as `(a > b) ? a : b` so ternary operator is not worse than `Math.max`
So why `Java` issues this warning message if there are no advantages replacing the ternary operator by `Math.max` method call?

Comment: Is it not IDE suggestion ?

Comment: `Math.max` shows your intention of getting the maximum better than `(a > b) ? a : b`.

Comment: I do not know, maybe it's IntelliJ. But again, why is it doing so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt that this is a real compiler warning, probably some IDE inspection/warning.

Nonetheless, you are correct, there are no hard technical reasons to prefer one over the other.

But: from the point of a human reader, using `Math.max()` has **one major** advantage: it is easier to read and understand. That simple.

Besides: do not duplicate code unless you have to.

Always remember: you write your code for your **human** readers. Compilers accept anything that is syntactically correct. But for your human readers, there is a difference between a condition and an assignment vs a very telling "take the maximum of two numbers".

Comment: The "soft" technical reason for preferring `Math.max()` is that it's an intrinsic, however [YMMV](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039104).

Comment: @Kayaman Honestly: when people have to worry about performance on a level that such bugs are a real problem for them, then maybe, just maybe, Java isnt the right answer for them anyway. But interesting point.

Comment: Yes, that was badly worded. It's not a reason to prefer `Math.max()`, it's a positive side effect of using it.

Answer (score 3):

`Math.max(a, b)` is more readable than the tenary statement because:

- the value `200` does not need to be repeated.
- there is no need to write and understand `>`

In general, the ternary is more powerful because it lets you do things like this:

```
    delay = (delay>200) ? 200 : delay;
    delay = (delay<200) ? delay : 200;
    delay = (delay>200) ? delay: 300;
```

The reader of your code needs to understand which of those things you are actually doing. It takes time to parse it and understand it is a simple `max()`.

The `max` shows your intention more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, there can be a performance advantage if the lower limit (in your case, 200) is not a constant but a derived value:

```
delay = (delay > readLimitFromFile()) ? delay : readLimitFromFile();
```

This could end up doing 2 expensive disk-read operations, when one operation would be sufficient. Using Math.max:

```
delay = Math.max(delay, readLimitFromFile());
```

would use only one disk-read operation.

Comment: But this answer relies on the developer to not simply use a variable for it in advance.

Comment: Well. You can always intentionally make code "stupid" to "prove" a point, can't you. I just dont find that very convincing.