# How to store SparseArray<Double> in Bundle?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sparse-matrix, parcelable, parcel

How can SparseArray be stored in a bundle ?

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    // ...
    SparseArray<Double> values = mAdapter.getValues();
    savedState.putSparseParcelableArray(values);
```

the code above results in compilation error that says

> "SparseArray< ? extends Parcelable > in Bundle cannot be applied to SparseArray< Double >".

How can it be solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSparseParcelableArray(java.lang.String,%20android.util.SparseArray%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E))  `SparseArray<? extends Parcelable> value)` mean The class and it's sub type is allowed but [Double](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html) does not implements `Parcelable` so you cannot use it with bundle persistence though you can have your customize bean class object implements parcelable

Answer (score 0):

for saving the SparseArray, put this data in the list and save that list the outState bundle.

And in onRestoreInstanceState, retrieve the list and convert it to the SparseArray again.

[for detailed explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252748/android-bundle-with-sparsearraystring?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This way loose an indexes, which is in some cases are sense (with the holes in the range)