# Why does .NET Native compile loop in reverse order?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86, micro-optimization, .net-native

I'm working on optimization techniques performed by the .NET Native compiler.
I've created a sample loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Function();
        }
```

And I've compiled it with Native. Then I disassembled the result `.dll` file with machine code inside in IDA. As the result, I have:

[image: IDA output]

(I've removed a few unnecessary lines, so don't worry that address lines are inconsistent)

I understand that `add esi, 0FFFFFFFFh` means really `subtract one from esi and alter Zero Flag if needed`, so we can jump to the beginning if zero hasn't been reached yet.

What I don't understand is why did the compiler reverse the loop?

I came to the conclusion that

```
LOOP:
add esi, 0FFFFFFFFh
jnz LOOP
```

is just faster than for example

```
LOOP:
inc esi
cmp esi, 064h
jl LOOP
```

But is it really because of that and is the speed difference really significant?

Comment: ADD with an immediate value is faster than INC and you also skip CMP...all of these in 3 lines of code. Then yes, difference is REALLY significant (both in size and in speed). Imagine to do this in ~30000 places in a real world program...

Comment: Yes, it's faster, and in general optimizers will apply any optimization they can that makes your code faster without changing the semantics of your program.

Comment: Regarding inverted direction, perhaps comparison to zero is quicker than comparison to a specific value?

Comment: Yes, because you don't even need a comparison. As you can (not) see :)

Comment: You've written the code both ways. If you want to know whether one way is faster than the other, then **run them**.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm not lazy and I would love to, but I'm on my work PC right now and I don't have any tools to run or benchmark assembly code :( Also I don't have administrator rights to install anything.

Comment: A for(;;) loop *normally* requires also checking that the start value observes the end condition.  Typical codegen is a branch forward to the condition code and then a branch back to the loop body code.  But the optimizer can take a shortcut here, it knows that the start value is already good and that you don't use the value of `i` anywhere so it can generate less code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`inc` might be slower than `add` because of the partial flag update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13383407/995714). Moreover `add` affects the zero flag so you don't need to use another `cmp` instruction. Just jump directly.

This is one famous type of [loop optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization)

> **reversal**: Loop reversal reverses the order in which values are assigned to the index variable. This is a subtle optimization which can help eliminate dependencies and thus enable other optimizations. Also, certain architectures utilize looping constructs at Assembly language level that count in a single direction only (e.g. decrement-jump-if-not-zero (DJNZ)).

- [Is it faster to count down than it is to count up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2823043/995714)
- [GCC Loop optimization](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3845/2563)

You can see the result for other compilers [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-O2',source:'//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aextern+void+function()%3B%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+100%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A++%7B%0A++++++function()%3B%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A++')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Comment: `inc` is slower then `add` by one clock cycle. Compare them in the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html). Scroll down to Appendix C and you can see the latency and throughput times of each x86/x64 instruction. 1 clock cycle may not seem significant, but if you got hundreds or thousands of loops, it will add up fast.

Comment: @Icemanind Those numbers don't reflect reality on the microarchitectures they describe (IvyBridge through Skylake; see the table earlier in that appendix). A `dec/jnz` loop can run at 1 iteration per cycle, and `inc/dec` have only 1 cycle latency for the integer register as part of other dep chains. Possibly Intel got the 2-cycle latency on IvyBridge through Broadwell (but not Skylake) from looking at latency to read EFLAGS, maybe including CF which would require a flag merge. But that's not a problem for dec / jnz even without fustion, or `dec / setz`. I only have a Skylake so I can't test :/

Comment: @Icemanind: Also note that those were *latency* numbers; the table you reference still listed inc/dec throughput at `0.25` cycles, i.e. 4-per-clock.  Anyway, Agner Fog's instruction tables, based on experimental testing, lists inc/dec at 1c latency / 0.25c throughput.  So does https://www.uops.info/table.html.  uops.info even measured latency from input to integer output and to flag output, and found 1 cycle in both cases: https://www.uops.info/html-instr/INC_R32.html.  (Not including the CF non-output)

Comment: @Icemanind: avoiding `dec` here is only useful if the code might run on Silvermont or Pentium 4.  Otherwise it's a waste of code-size for mainstream Intel and AMD.

Answer (score 2):

Your conclusion is correct: *inverted* cycle will target `0` (cycle will ends when register value reach `0`), so that `Add` will set zero flag used in conditional branch.

This way you don't need dedicated `Cmp` which leads to: 1) size optimization 2) it's also faster (conclusion from compiler programmers decision and another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430464/1997232)).

That's pretty common assembler trick to write loop targeting `0`. I am surprised you understand assembler, but don't know (asking) about it.